# Converting a string into a date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script which joins 2 feeds and displays them on the screen

```
$.when( //get feed 1, //get feed 2 ).done(function(a1, a2){

    var data = a1[0]response.Data.feed.entries.concat(a2[0].responseData.feed.entries);

    var sorted = data.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(a.publishedDate > b.publishedDate) {
            return 1
        }
        if(a.publishedDate < b.publishedDate) {
            return -1
        }
        return 0
    });

    for( i = o; i <= sorted.length - 1; i++ ) {
        document.write(sorted[i].title);
        document.write(sorted[i].publishedDate);
    }

});
```

This returns all the rows, but it doesn't sort the rows.  The sorting seems completely random.  I'm assuming it's because the dates are formatted as follows in the JSON data:

```
Mon, 23 Sep 2013 04:37:45 -0700
```

1. What does that `-0700` mean
2. How do I convert that date string into a proper date object so I can sort the results correctly?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: And the -0700 is the timezone offset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `-0700` means the UTC offset `UTC-07:00`.
2. I'm strongly recommend you to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) library to deal with date and time, formatting and conversions to make your "Date & Time JavaScript Life" easy and funny.

As [Alnitak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782/alnitak) said this particular format is accepted by `Date.parse` therefore if you use one of accepted formats you can just use native JavaScript for sorting.

```
var dateStrings,
    sortDates;

dateStrings = [
    'Mon, 23 Sep 2013 04:37:45 -0700',
    'Sun, 22 Sep 2013 05:27:32 +0300',
    'Mon, 23 Sep 2013 03:14:17 -0700'
];

sortDates = function(dateStrings) {
    return dateStrings.sort(function(a, b) {
        return new Date(a) - new Date(b);
    });
};

console.log(sortDates(dateStrings));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/MwN9A/)

The variable `sorted` in your code snippet could be properly retrieved in this way:

```
var sorted = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.publishedDate) - new Date(b.publishedDate);
});
```

Comment: nice, but overkill when the given date string is already in an accepted format (i.e. RFC 822)

Comment: Thanks @Alnitak, added a pure JavaScript solution as well.

Comment: Not sure how this works.  Maybe my question wasn't clear?  The JSON data returned has many key:value pairs.  and the `publishDate` is one of those pairs.  So I would want all the `rows` (so to speak)  sorted based on the sorting of `publishDate`.  I can't see how the above will solve that?  So basically, sort the JSON data based on `publishDate`, then display all the data on the users screen in the sorted order.

Comment: Personally I would actually replace the strings with their object representations, and _then_ sort them.  Doing the conversion _within_ the sort callback can result in `O(n log n)` conversions from string to date and subsequent comparisons.  Look up "Schwartzian Transform"

Comment: So use your function where you make a comparison but compare not `a.publishedDate > b.publishedDate` but `new Date(a.publishedDate) > new Date(b.publishedDate)`.

Comment: Agreed with @Alnitak about the computational complexity. If you have a really big input array and see that the sorting works slowly, it could be useful to make Date objects in that array before comparison.

Comment: @EugeneNaydenov p.s. your sorter function can just return `dateA - dateB` - no need for the -1, 0, 1 logic.  JS will use the numeric `.valueOf()` directly when you attempt to subtract two date objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the string to `new Date(...)` to convert to a real `Date` object.

To sort however you also need to pass a specific sort function because default Javascript `sort` on arrays just converts elements to string and compares the result of conversion (thus any `"Mon"`day will happen to be placed before any `"Sun"`day).

Something that should work is

```
dates.sort(function(a, b){ return a - b; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, -0700 means.. is `7 hours earlier than Greenwich Mean` ...yor can check more in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9207:00)

And if you want to convert any date properly, i strongly recommend you to use the library DateJS (http://www.datejs.com/)

You can use syntatic sugarr..!! to create your object...

```
Date.parse('Thu, 1 July 2013 20:20:20');
```

voila.. its very easy...